# MsiPackage conditional install: Don't uninstall if it detects package is already installed

Tags: installation, wix, uninstallation, bootstrapper, burn

I'm using Wix Bootstrapper and want to install a few applications through .msi packages alongside my main application. These applications may be installed in the target PC already so I need to detect these first and skip installation if they are already installed. Furthermore, during uninstallation, these applications should not be uninstalled since the Wix Bootstrapper did not install them.

I've tried to use the `InstallCondition` attribute but (as expected) it uninstalls if it detects the application is already installed.

My Bundle.wxs looks like this:

```
...
  <Bundle>
    <util:FileSearch Id='CheckApplicationX' Path='[ProgramFilesFolder]ApplicationX\ApplicationX.exe' Variable='ApplicationXFile' Result='exists' />
    <Chain DisableRollback="yes">
      ...
      <MsiPackage Id="InstallApplicationX" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" EnableFeatureSelection="no" SourceFile="..\application-x.msi" Name="Application X" DisplayName="Application X" ForcePerMachine="yes" InstallCondition="NOT ApplicationXFile" />
      ...
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
...
```

Any help/hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect if the applications are installed by looking in the Windows Registry and try to identify if there are "traces" left by those applications.

You can use the `RegistrySearch` tag to perform a conditional evaluation of the registry entries you're looking for and then deny the installation.

There's an example on Wix Website available at **[this link](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html)**.

The following example shows how you can define if .NET 2.0 is installed on the target machine

```
<Property Id="NETFRAMEWORK20">
<RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727"
                Name="Install"
                Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've read the docs and have used FileSearch over RegistrySearch.

Also, I cannot use bal:Condition element as this will stop the entire bundle installation. I just need to skip the particular MsiPackage if it detects it is previously installed.

Comment: if you have the installation of the MsiPackage as a Custom Action, you can then use <Custom Action="IdOfYourCustomActionElement" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[Installed OR YOURPROPERTY]]></Custom>